# How to Scale my Sprites up/down depends on screen resolution in cocos2dx?

Tags: cocos2d-x

I'm having problem working with multi screen solution. I've done the search around but still couldn't find the solution since those answer were oudated / using deprecated method or unclear to me. After 3 hours of searching and tried many different advices, I still couldn't get it done and I got confused so I have to create this topic. Your attention and help is very much appreciated.

**My situation:** I'm working with `designResolutionSize = cocos2d::Size(1280, 720);`. It works fine on my PC monitor (with screen solution 1600x900) but when I install my app on a set-top box and run it on a **30 inch or 40 inch TV**. My sprites don't scale up to fit the TV screen, they looks too tiny.

**My question** How should I make my App scale up/down depends on the device resolution to fit the screen?

My AppDelegate.cpp:

```
static cocos2d::Size designResolutionSize = cocos2d::Size(1280, 720);

bool AppDelegate::applicationDidFinishLaunching(){
    // Get the Director instance
    auto mDirector = Director::getInstance();
    // Get the GL View Container
    auto mGLView = mDirector->getOpenGLView();
        //Set up View Container if there's no available one
    if (!mGLView)
    {   
        mGLView = GLViewImpl::create("NGTV Launcher");
        /*mGLView->setFrameSize(1280, 720);*/
        mGLView->setFrameSize(1600, 900);
        /*mGLView->setFrameSize(1920, 1080);*/
        mDirector->setOpenGLView(mGLView);
    }

    mGLView->setDesignResolutionSize(designResolutionSize.width, designResolutionSize.height, ResolutionPolicy::EXACT_FIT);
    // Innitialize a Scene with createScene()
    auto mScene = HelloWorld::createScene();
    // Run the scenee
    mDirector->runWithScene(mScene);

    return true;
}
```

Comment: You should scale your Sprites. 
`yourSprite->setScale(screenWidth / yourSprite->getcontentSize().width * kYourSpriteScale, screenHeight / yourSprite->getcontentSize().height * kYourSpriteScale);` if `kYourSpriteScale == 1` sprite will be the size of the screen

Comment: Hi @Darvydas, thanks for your advice. However, Is there any better way to make my App scale automatically base on screen size? Since I have a lot of sprites declared here and there in my app, it takes too much effort to scale them all one by one in such a large source code. It also isn't good for maintainance code later on.

Comment: Actually I do not know that, I always scale and position everything myself acording to a device size. Also what about different aspect ratios? How you are going to handle that?

Comment: Quote from [my old answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/90405/cocos2d-x-supporting-multi-resolution-using-density-independent-pixels/90406#90406): "In fact you just need to set your `DesignResolution` and then just imagine your target device will has this resolution." Actually it works like that.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you need is `GLView::setDesignResolutionSize()` and `Director::setContentScaleFactor()`.

http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Multi_resolution_support